# Determining order of ARMA model in R

Tags: r, time-series, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

I am working with a time series dataset and wish to do some ARMA modeling in R. I believe that I have detrended and deseasonalized the data correctly and now have a stationary time series.

Now the question is, what order ARMA model should I use? I know this is typically determined from the ACF and PACF plots but what mine tell me seem inconclusive. It's not clear the behavior of cutting off/tailing off of these graphs. Did I go wrong somewhere? Is my series not stationary? (PS. I'm not looking to do any differencing at this point)

Are there any functions in R that read a stationary time series and output the suggested order of the best ARMA model? Or any other advice moving forward with ARMA modeling?

This is my stationary series
[image: stationary series]

And this is my ACF and PACF plots (the data is monthly, hence why the lags are decimals)
[image]

At this point, my best guess would be a AR(3) model, but the PACF still spikes after lag 3 so I'm not sure.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: *Are there any functions in R that read a stationary time series and output the suggested order of the best ARMA model?* Yes. See `auto.arima` from the `forecast` package.